# how to create Nullable<T> within function?

Tags: c#, generics, null

I have a generic class for an array operation.

I have a function which should return `T` if a condition is met but return null if the condition is not met.

Minnimal reproducible example:

```
internal Nullable<T> AppendPoint(T input)
{
    Nullable<T> result = null; // Type T must be a non nullable value type...
    if (Length == Array.Length)
    {
        // result = Array[TailIndex];
    }
    //
    // add new element to array logic here
    //
    return result; //no compiler error
    return null; // works
}
```

Specifically, this function should insert a value into a circular array.
This may Overwrite a previous value which should be returned, if it is beeing overwritten.

Apparently, I can return null, I can create the function with Nullable but I cant create a Nullable within the function.

Comment: I think (not tested) `internal Nullable<T> AppendPoint(T input) where T : struct` should do the trick.
Also `Nullable<T> result = default; ` should fix it.

Comment: What's the question? How to fix the compilation error? The message already explains what's wrong. The type must be restricted to a value type, ie `struct`. `default` isn't needed. `Nullable<T>` is only needed for value types, a reference type allows nulls

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a constrain on you generic type T, to tell the compiler T can't be a nullable type. Otherwise, `Nullable<T>` is not an acceptable expression for the compiler.

```
internal Nullable<T> AppendPoint(T input) where T : struct
```

Comment: Error Message: Constraints are not allowed on non generic declarations

Comment: The constraint needs to be on the class, not the method.